# How to create an Angular factory service to access ASP.NET server-side cache

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-services

We are creating an ASP.NET MVC application which uses AngularJS framework. This is a multi-lingual application and resource values in each language are stored in the database.

On the server-side, we load all of our resources from the database into HttpRuntimeCache when the user logs in to the application and use it throughout our views.

We want to create an AngularJS factory service which we can use to access the resources in HttpRuntimeCache.

For example:

1. User clicks login
2. ASP.NET MVC Application loads resources into HttpRuntimeCache
3. User is redirected to root of application (Home/Index).
4. Angular application is initialized
5. When user views a page which needs these resources from HttpRuntimeCace, we will get the value via the service

   - When this service is called, it will first check if it has already loaded the resource dictionary
   - If it has not yet loaded, it will call an MVC action method, which will return the resource dictionary as JSON, and the service will use that response to load the dictionary
   - If it has already been loaded, it will just return the value from the dictionary based on the key which has been requested

**What is the best way to achieve this scenario?**

Below is what we have so far. The issue with our current solution is that the service is returning the value before the dictionary has a chance to load.

```
angular.module("MyApp").factory('cacheService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    var obj = { resourcesLoaded: false };

    obj.loadResourceDictionary = function () {
        obj.resourcesLoaded = false;

        $http.get("/MyApp/Cache/GetResourceDictionary")
            .success(function (data) {
                obj.resourceDictionary = data;
                obj.resourcesLoaded = true;
            });
    }

    obj.getResourceValue = function (resourceKeyName) {
        if (!obj.resourcesLoaded) {
            obj.loadResourceDictionary();
        }
        return obj.resourceDictionary[resourceKeyName];
    }

    return obj;
}]);
```

**EDIT w/ Usage example in Angular controller (we also want to use this service in a directive):**

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller("MyAppCtrl", ['cacheService', function (cacheService) {
    var self = this;
    self.test = function () {
        var value = cacheService.getResourceValue('Err_lbl_UserExist');
    }
}]);

<div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl as myAppCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myAppCtrl.test()">Test Angular CacheService</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
angular.module("MyApp").factory('cacheService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
  var service = { 
    obj.getResourceValue = function () {
        return $http.get("/MyApp/Cache/GetResourceDictionary")
            .success(function (data) {
                return data
            });
    }
  }
  return service;
}]);
```

And for your controller method:

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller("MyAppCtrl", ['cacheService', function (cacheService) {
    var self = this;
    self.test = function () {
        var value = null;
        cacheService.getResourceValue().then(function (data){
              value = data['Err_lbl_UserExist'];
        }
    }
}]);

<div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl as myAppCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myAppCtrl.test()">Test Angular CacheService</button>
</div>
```

$http.get is an asynch function , therefore will block until data is received. All you have to do is handle errors which is not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code in your answer does not block the thread, when obj.resourcesLoaded is false, it doesn't block the thread until the dictionary is loaded and the returned value is 'undefined'.

Comment: Show me where the function where this service is being used.

Comment: I have edited the question with a usage example within an Angular controller.

Comment: Is there an easy way to block the $http call within the cacheService? I would prefer not to have to write ".then()" and perform additional logic whenever i want to access a value within a controller/directive.

Comment: The function will block, however javascript is an asynchrounous language, therefore the code will continue running and the function will not return anything